# How to efficiently find and remove 1 pixel bands of image intensity changes?

Tags: image-processing, edge-detection, distortion, sobel

We're having some visual artifacts on a normal map for a shader because of some bands of single pixels which are very contrast to their surroundings. Just to be clear, edges are not an issue, only these single pixel bands.

Using something like typical Sobel edge detection would not work in this case because on top of such a band, it would detect 0. I can think of other modifications to the kernel which might works such as

```
-1 -2 -1
 2  4  2
-1 -2 -1
```

but I assumed that there was likely a "correct" mathematical way to do such an operation.

In the end, I want to smooth these lines out using the surrounding pixels (so a selective blur). These lines could appear in any orientation, so if I were to use the above kernel, I would need to apply it in both direction and add it to get the line intensity similar to when applying the Sobel kernel.

Comment: You don't avtually say what the problem is with the bands - only that they are contrasty and Sobel doesn't work. Do you want to remove them? Enhance them? Mark them? How do they look? Are they horizontal or vertical?

Comment: I don't see how a Sobel filter could not detect a 1 pixel band.  If we had this particular band that has a higher contrast than the band above or below (or to the left and right if it's a vertical band), then you should find strong gradients along this band.  Can you show us an example or any code that you've written to illustrate your point?  I'm having a hard time picturing what the problem is.

Comment: @rayryeng - The problem with the Sobel in this case is that if you applied to to a line which is exactly one pixel wide in brightness, you would get there being no edge directly on the line, but rather an edge two pixels above and two pixels below.  picture [-1,-2,-1, 0,0,0,1,2,1]. The line would lay directly on the 0's and the the upper and lower would lay directly on the non-line (for the purpose of this example, they would be the same). the actual edge would be detected right above the line and right below it. Additionally, I want to preserve edges that are not a single pixel wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have lines of 1 pixel width in your image that are brighter or darker than their surroundings and you want to find them and remove them from the image and replace the removed pixels by an average of the local neighborhood.

I developed an algorithm for this and it works on my example data (since you did not give any data). It has two parts:

**Identification of lines**

I could not think of a simple, yet effective filter to detect lines (which are connected, so one would probably need to look at correlations). So I used a simple single pixel detection filter:

```
-1 -1 -1
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1
```

and then some suitable thresholding.

**Extrapolation of data from outside of a mask to the mask**

A very elegant solution (using only convolutions) is to take the data outside the mask and convolve it with a gaussian, then take negative mask and convolve it with the very same gaussian, then divide both pixelwise. The result within the mask is the desired blurring.

What it is mathematically: a weighted averaging of the data.

Here is my phantom data:

[image]

And this is the identification of the lines

[image]

And the final result shows that the distortion has been suppressed tenfold:

[image]

And finally my code (in Matlab):

```
%% create phantom data with lines (1pixel wide bands)
[x, y] = ndgrid(1:100, 1:100);
original = 3 * x - 2 * y + 100 * sin(x / 2) + 120 * cos(y / 3); % funny shapes
bw = original > mean(original(:)); % black and white
distortion = bwmorph(bw,'remove'); % some lines
data = original + max(original(:)) * distortion; % phantom

% show
figure();
subplot(1,3,1); imagesc(original); axis image; colormap(hot); title('original');
subplot(1,3,2); imagesc(distortion); axis image; title('distortion');
subplot(1,3,3); imagesc(data); axis image; title('image');

%% line detection
% filter by single pixel filter
pixel_filtered = filter2([-1,-1,-1;-1,8,-1;-1,-1,-1], data);

% create mask by simple thresholding
mask = pixel_filtered > 0.2 * max(pixel_filtered(:)); 

% show
figure();
subplot(1,2,1); imagesc(pixel_filtered); axis image; colormap(hot); title('filtered');
subplot(1,2,2); imagesc(mask); axis image; title('mask');

%% line removal and interpolation
% smoothing kernel: gaussian
smooth_kernel = fspecial('gaussian', [3, 3], 1);
smooth_kernel = smooth_kernel ./ sum(smooth_kernel(:)); % normalize to one

% smooth image outside mask and divide by smoothed negative mask 
smoothed = filter2(smooth_kernel, data .* ~mask) ./ filter2(smooth_kernel, ~mask);

% withing mask set data to smoothed
reconstruction = data .* ~mask + smoothed .* mask;

% show
figure();
subplot(1,3,1); imagesc(reconstruction); axis image; colormap(hot); title('reconstruction');
subplot(1,3,2); imagesc(original); axis image; title('original');
subplot(1,3,3); imagesc(reconstruction - original); axis image; title('difference');
```

Comment: Doing some basic on paper analysis of single pixel, either 0 or 1 values with both of our kernels, they appear to have the same contrast on horizontal and vertical lines, but my version appears better on diagonal lines. Still voted up and marked as answer because it works in one pass and is a very well thought out answer.

Comment: @David Thanks. And you can freely combine everything and maybe only use my extrapolation. Don't know if you use Matlab, Python or C++.

Comment: Python is what I've been using. I've coded it up and am trying both of ours now on the our real data set.

Comment: Looks like both kernels work about the exact same on our real world data set. Thanks again for the help!